# C# app Read Data 32 bit(Signed) From Pro-Server

Tags: c#

I'm learning about Pro-face's Pro-Server EX,
I have a question: how to read the value of 16 bit (Signed), 32 bit (Signed)

For example: Currently the value at Server is 40.5 but when I read the result is 405 (Int32)

int iRet = 0;   // For return value of function
ProEasyDotNet.ProEasy.EasyObject  oData;    // EasyObject type variables for reading
// Execution of reading
iRet = ProEasyDotNet.ProEasy.ReadSymbolVariant( txt_Nope.Text, txt_Groupitem.Text, out oData );
System.Array arReadData = oData.GetArray();
Int32[] value = (Int32[])arReadData.GetValue(0); //405

Thanks.